# Story about Neil Armstrong being transported across the galaxy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, moon

Attempting to search for the answer myself (and also ignited by current events), I recalled another short story I read back in 2006 that involved Neil Armstrong getting caught in a wormhole while traveling to the moon on Apollo 11. He was transported across the galaxy to a different solar system with an M-class planet much like earth populated only by women and small, male woodland creatures (similar to elves). There was a fierce battle between the women with Neil Armstrong and the creatures that ultimately led to the women being victorious, and they eventually enslaved the creatures. As an act of gratitude to Neil, the women sent him and his team back directly to the moon. Does anyone remember what the name of this story was?